# After deployed to server, website UI does not display properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an ASP.Net MVC5 based web app. I am using Bootstrap for the UI. 
On my machine everything is perfect. After login, the following page is shown.
[Analytics page as on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVgd5.png)

After I deploy to the web server, I get the following page post login.

[Analytics page from the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Ipc.png)

You can see that the page from server is all messed up. It is almost like all divs are showing up with their borders. I am not sure what is going wrong here. Any inputs are most welcome.

Update:

I have another application "TalkApp" that has the same login page as this Analytics App. "TalkApp" UI has no issues.

So I checked the page source for the login page. The TalkApp has these links:

```
<link href="/TADATalk/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/TADATalk/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="/TADATalk/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>


<script src="/TADATalk/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<script src="/TADATalk/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

<script src="/TADATalk/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>

<script src="/TADATalk/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Whereas, the AnalyticsApp did not have these. Instead it had ..v="e34hgd5677.." type of entries. I removed use of bundles from AnalyticsApp and directly added the link refs. Now the UI loads properly.

So the question still stands: why did bundles not work with one app but work with another app (which is also deployed on the server).

Comment: Are you making sure that you are refreshing the css from the prod server? IE Clear your local cache. Have you made sure that your css was properly deployed (IE it has all the bootstrap* css in your main bundled css)?

Comment: I was only running in chrome. "refreshing the css from prod server"....I don't get that.

Comment: Oh I see. By IE you mean i.e. (that is). Can you explain further.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of as to why your bundles aren't loading but hardcoding css links does, is if you're not including them in your _Layout.cshtml. Here is an example from my application.

**BundleConfig.cs (RegisterBundles method)**

```
.... other bundles ...

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));

... other bundles ...
```

**_Layout.cshtml***

```
... other head stuff ...

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css") <--- this name is the "virtual path" to that bundle of styles

... other head stuff ...
```

You define the bundles in BundleConfig.cs, which gets called from your Global.asax.cs.ApplicationStart() method:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            ViewEngineConfig.RegisterEngines(ViewEngines.Engines);


        }
```

This should all be setup in the older template startup project.